# Row selectable in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

As the title, I want to make a row selectable by some conditions with using ag-grid in angularjs.

In the past, I used ui-grid and its property "isRowSelectable" to make it.

```
$scope.options = {
    ...
    isRowSelectable:function(row){
    return row.entity.taskExecutionStatus===0?true:false;
  }
}
```

However, the ag-grid doesn't have the property "isRowSelectable" like ui-grid.
How can I fix it now?

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thx, I have reedited the question

Answer (score 1):

Check if the row is selectable or not in `gridOptions.onSelectionChanged()` function.
If false, then use `node.setSelected(false, false, true)` to deselect the row;

Answer (score 0):

A valid solution is to use checkbox selection when you don't want all the rows to be selectable, something like this:

```
$scope.options = {
  columnDefs: [
    {headerName: "",
      width: 17,
      cellStyle: {'padding': '2px'},
      checkboxSelection: function(row){
        return row.entity.taskExecutionStatus===0?true:false;
      }
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
  rowSelection: 'single', // or 'multiple'
  suppressRowClickSelection: true,
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To select Single row in ag-grid:

```
 $scope.Gridoptions:{
    columnDefs:...,

    rowData:...,

      onRowClicked: RowClick,

     rowSelection: 'single',

    };

 function RowClick(param) {

    //To Find CurrentRow Index  
    var currentRowIndex = param.rowIndex;

    //GridData

    var gridData = $scope.gridOptionsInstrumentRegister.rowData;

    //Item ShowS RoWData

    var Item = params.data;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
checkboxSelection: function (params) {
      params.node.selectable = false; // this will explicitly restrict to select (useful in select all)
      return true/false; // this will show or hide the checkbox
}
```

Comment: Generally code only answers aren't that useful - you should explain how this code works.